# geolocation-marker.js conflict with markerclusterer.js

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map but conflict. when I click or zoom the marker, all marker disappear. but when I remove the marker clusterer all fine, but so many marker. I use [geolocation-marker.js](https://chadkillingsworth.github.io/geolocation-marker/) & [markerclusterer.js](http://visit2indonesia.com/maps/markerclusterer.js). any ide for this problem? thanks

My HTML

```
<div style="width:100%; height:100%;">
            <div id="map">
                <span style="color:Gray;">
                <img style="margin: 0px auto; display: block; width: 50%;" src="images/circle-loading-animation.gif"></img>
                </span>
            </div> </div>
        </div><!-- Map Ends display -->
```

This is my Java script geolocation-marker

```
GeoMarker = new GeolocationMarker();
            GeoMarker.setCircleOptions({fillColor: '#808080'});

            google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(GeoMarker, 'position_changed', function() {
            map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
            map.fitBounds(this.getBounds());
            });

            //marker follow & center screen
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            map.setCenter(geolocpoint);
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(GeoMarker, 'geolocation_error', function(e) {
            alert('There was an error obtaining your position. Message: ' + e.message);
            });

            GeoMarker.setMap(map);
```

And this my script markerclusterer

```
//markerCluster
            var mcOptions = {
                gridSize: 50,
                maxZoom: 15
            };
            var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);



              .....................................................
              ....................................................
                markerCluster.addMarker(marker, true);
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: [link](http://visit2indonesia.com/maps/index.php) for Demo

Comment: `Error 401 - Unauthorized`, `Authorization is required to access the requested resource. For further assistance please contact the web site owner.`  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**.

Comment: hai @geocodezip sory for the link...please visit new link [link](http://visit2indonesia.com/map)  thanks for your help

Comment: I can't help you.  Your link is still password protected.  Third request:  please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue **in the question itself**.  Please don't provide **required** information in a link, put that information in the question, links can die, the problems in them get fixed, removing context from the question.

Comment: @geocodezip its last link [demo](http://www.visit2indonesia.com/maps/index.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the Conflict, it's because I add `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>` in head. And  when I click or zoom the marker, all marker disappear. But when I change the url above to `script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&sensor=true"></script>` all marker it's fine.

Thanks